# Interested in how these particular supplements work together

Tags: diet, digestion, constipation

I feel there's a lack of information about taking a wide variety of supplements, however, people are increasingly taking a wider variety of supplements. I'm interested in finding out how these particular supplements interact with one another, especially over a period of time. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hgFzhae3SEIxHvN0V3P4IRzxJbk-ZsD_Jku8gV83-dQ/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Welcome to SE Health. Please read the rules. It is not meant for personal advice. Only your doctor can answer this question based on an evaluation of your medical conditions, medications, allergies, and physical exam.  IF you rewrote this as a question how to determine the interaction of medications and supplements, listing the supplements and what you have found so far in trying to answer the question yourself, then your question might fit the rules of SE Health and be answerable.

Comment: I am not looking for health advice. I am only looking for general information about how the the supplements I'm taking react with each other.

Comment: I can understand why you would give clinical background, thinking it helps people answer it better, but that is a common mistake - once you provide a clinical story/background, it becomes medical advice. That's basically the beginning of a clinical visit, and we go down the rabbit hole of potential misdiagnosis and mismanagement. It can be downright dangerous.  So if you want to ask that, just ask what you want to know about those supplements.

Comment: Hello DoctorWhom, I have updated my question even further to remove all traces of the irrelevant background information.

Answer (score 4):

SE Health is not meant for personal advice. Only your doctor can answer this question based on an evaluation of your medical conditions, medications, allergies, and physical exam.

What I can do is guide you toward the right resources.

Make a list of these things you are on, a list of your medical history, a list of medication or food reactions you've had in the past, and what you wrote in the question.  Take it with you to the doctor.

Because of the supplements you take and diagnosis of Leaky Gut, I would recommend a doctor who practices functional medicine or a doctor of naturopathy - at least in the USA.  I know for a fact that most MD/DO training does not cover very many alternative medications and supplements.  Part of the reason is that there is limited evidence about some of them, part is that they are not always regulated or safe, and part is that the pharmaceutical industry tends to dominate what is taught in med school (they generate the most evidence through extensive research that costs big $$).

Treatments of ANY kind range in evidence of effectiveness from 0 to extremely strong, depending on what quality research is able to show us. There IS evidence for safety and efficacy of many alt meds/supplements, but I am not an expert in which resources those are.

That is why I point you to one of those specialists who DO use those resources regularly.  I have met and listened to a number of very knowledgeable and evidence-based doctors of naturopathy and functional medicine doctors, but that does not mean that all of them practice strongly evidence-based medicine. I recommend that you request that the doctor provide you with the resources that support their recommendations so that you can read further and educate yourself on them.

Medication interaction checkers exist online, but there are a couple caveats.  One, they might not be accurate with supplements (or even have them listed).  Two, there is no way to input your medical history.  If you have damaged your liver drinking, for example, your liver enzymes may not work right and medications can build up or behave differently.  This is why you need a doctor to talk with you for your individual case.

Good luck with your learning process.  It is good that you are asking these questions about safety and your health!  It's just not the right way to ask questions on Health SE.

Comment: I really like your more nuanced description of naturopathy doctors, compared, for example, to [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturopathy): "Naturopathy or naturopathic medicine is a form of pseudoscientific, alternative medicine ... based on vitalism and folk medicine, rather than evidence-based medicine." (Btw, I would not see a naturopathic doc myself, and I am a proud _Wikipedian_, so I'm not coming from a biased perspective in that regard.)

Comment: I was just providing a bit of background more than seeking medical advice. I was just curious about the use of these supplements together and over a period of time, the responses would have no impact on my decisions. I've never heard of Naturopathy to be honest, it also sounds like something I would keep away from usually. I'd also like to add that I do not feel I'm seriously ill and in need of urgent advice, I'm just interested. There are many reasons why my condition could have improved (it was not fatal); I'm fit and healthy and under 30. I have increased my fibre intake, quit drinking. etc

Comment: I will take a look at some of the medication interaction checkers, thanks. I'm not one of those people that believe in things like homeopathy. I think what I'm taking are just reasonable supplements of things that are naturally made within the body or are ingested to repair and maintain certain functions of it. Hopefully I'm not taking useless sugar pills.

Comment: That is a common mistake - once you provide a clinical story/background, it becomes medical advice.  Even though it seems that it is to help provide context and guide how someone might answer, that's basically the beginning of a clinical visit.

Comment: There is a difference between homeopathy and naturopathy and functional medicine.  Read about them.  Treatments range in evidence of effectiveness from 0 to extremely strong.  I suggested those two types of medical providers because you are on several supplements and leaky gut syndrome is not fully a mainstream diagnosis (at least not yet), so seeing someone familiar with your diagnosis and what you take is better than coming into the average generalist with an MD or DO and limited awareness of those things.  I wish there WERE more research on supplements and alternative medicine treatments!

Comment: If you are taking supplements for your health, Naturopathy is a natural fit for that.  My ND is also an MD and an herbalist.  She takes all major insurance, has hospital privileges.   You might be surprised what is out there if you start asking.  I found her name through asking at my natural health store where i buy my vitamins & such.  I had no idea we had an MD that was an ND locally.  Naturopathy is *not* homeopathy.  People who do homeopath are Homeopaths.